# How to Serialize a object use JavaScript? Such as window，function

Tags: javascript

I know how to serialize String and map. But I want to Serialize window OBJ.
like this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(window)

ex)

```
Object.keys(window).forEach(function(key, index) {
    console.log(key + ':' + window[key]);
});
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Qmd.png